# Popping out a number from stack in c++?

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

my code so far is...

```
struct stack_struct
{
    int number;
    struct stack_struct *next_number;
};

stack_struct *mainStruct;

class stack_class
{
private:

    struct stack_struct *head;

public:
    stack_class();
    ~stack_class();
    void pushNumber(int number);
    void popNumber();
    void findNumber();
    void clearStack();
    void sizeFinder();
    void printStack();
    void reverseStack();//Extra Credit
};
stack_class mainClassStack;

stack_struct *pointerFunc,*tailPointer=NULL,*pointerFunc3,*printPointer;

stack_class::stack_class()
{
    head=NULL;
}

stack_class::~stack_class()
{
    clearStack();
    cout<<"\nList Cleared.\n";
    system("pause");
}


void stack_class::popNumber()
{
    stack_struct *pointerPop=NULL,*pointerPop2=NULL;
    int popCounter=0,i=0;
    pointerPop2=tailPointer;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nNo Member to Delete.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        while(pointerPop2)
        {
            popCounter++;
            //cout<<pointerFunc3->number<<endl;
            pointerPop2=pointerPop2->next_number;
        }
        pointerPop=tailPointer;
        while(i<(popCounter-2))
        {
            pointerPop=pointerPop->next_number;
            i++;
        }
        pointerPop->next_number=NULL;
        delete head;
        head=pointerPop;
    }

}

void stack_class::printStack()
{
    pointerFunc3=tailPointer;
    if(tailPointer==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nNo Members in List.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\n\nList Is:\n";
        while(pointerFunc3)
        {
            cout<<pointerFunc3->number<<endl;
            pointerFunc3=pointerFunc3->next_number;
        }
    }

}
```

Popping works fine as long as it is not the last number. If the last number is popped (list is empty), and I try to print the list, the program infinitely prints garbage. If I try to pop a number after the list is empty, the program freezes. How do I fix these?

Comment: Why are you using globals everywhere? Also you have no code which ever sets `head` to `NULL`. Remember that setting a pointer to `NULL` does not change anything else which points to the same thing.

Comment: When popping elements just do nothing if the stack is empty. When printing, your code shouldn't print anything if the stack is empty (you should be able to tell if this is the case)

Comment: @Dave I am using globals because I used a switch in the program.

Comment: ... what? You mean like a `switch/case`? That has nothing to do with globals.

Comment: @Dave if I use locals, and want to use in different switch cases, compiler says not declared in scope.

Comment: Define your variables inside the *function*, not the switch cases or global scope. Just don't use globals. They're terrible.

Comment: Lots of non-documented, homework-like code : vote to close. Please learn how to use a debugger and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Change your popNumber() like this,

```
void stack_class::popNumber()
{
    stack_struct *pointerPop=NULL,*pointerPop2=NULL;
    int popCounter=0,i=0;
    pointerPop2=tailPointer;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nNo Member to Delete.\n";
    }
    else if(head->next_number==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nThe Poped element is"<<head->number;
        head=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
       // Your Code;    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also allways to create one dummy node for solve this. Otherwise:

```
int stack_class::popNumber()
{
    if(head==NULL)
        throw new Exception("Stack is empty");
    int result = head->number;
    delete head;
    head = head->next_number;
    return result;
}

void stack_class::pushNumber(int number)
{
    stack_struct *elem= new stack_struct();
    elem->number = number;
    elem->next_number = head;
    head = elem;
}
```

!!!!!try do not use globals variables like (stack_class mainClassStack;

stack_struct *pointerFunc,*tailPointer=NULL,)

Answer (score 0):

> include cstdlib for exit

```
    int Stack::pop()
    {   if (top == NULL)
            {
             cerr <<"Stack is empty";
             exit(1);
            }
        else
            {   
             Node* zap = top;
             top = zap->link;
             int return_value = zap->n;
             delete zap;
             return return_value;
            }
     }
```

Qazi you have to put the `if(top==NULL)`check at the start of both procedures.